# page transitions with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd to create some transitions between pages. I've made it this way:

```
    $("div.fading").css('display', 'none');
    $("div.fading").fadeIn(500);
    $("a.fade").click(function(event){  
         event.preventDefault();
         link = event.href;
         $("div.fading").fadeOut(500, redirect(link));
     });
```

in redirect have I used window.location and it has been working, but the fadeIn effect has been running for every page which has been loaded. I didn't like that, so I'm trying make it with ajax. It should allow me to call the fadeIn function as a callback function in jquery. I have this code,

```
$(".fading").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = this.href;
    $(".fade").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            success: function(){
                $(".fade").fadeIn(300);
            }
        });
    });
```

which is not fully working..All effects are OK, but page which I get after fadeIn is simply the same that faded out..IMHO can I do it another way with .load() function, I tried to implement that, but there were too some problems:-)Does anybody know what I should do to make it fully working?Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the page via ajax, but you're not replacing the contents of the current `.fade` div before you call `fadeIn()`. I've modified your code to do that below. `.load()` should do the same thing a little cleaner.

```
$(".fading").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = this.href;
    $(".fade").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            success: function(pageHTML){
                 $(".fade").html(pageHTML);
                $(".fade").fadeIn(300);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems good, but I should load and replace entire code of the  page and I don't know how to select it..When I use window as the DOM selector, it's not working, when I use html, it doesn't load stylesheets and so on..This is exactly the problem which I have had with the .load() function..

Comment: .load() will let you load a page fragment using a css id selector. You might want to consider using an iframe or having inline css or using css import when you get your content via ajax. You could also have the css styles on the page so that everything displays correctly when you load the new content.

Comment: Hi, thank for your advice, I'd tried CSS @import feature, unfortunately it wasn't successfull. I will try to take the obtained data in pieces and replace only the changed sections(title, body,..).I hope it's a good way:-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing any used of the data returned. In the success function you'll need to do something like:

```
$('.fade').html(data);
```

Then and you can fade it back in with the page having been updated.